# xfce4-screenshot + flatpak GIMP

Tags: gimp, screenshot, flatpak

I recently installed GIMP 2.10 with flatpak and now I can't send the screenshot to GIMP directly. I can send it to another viewer and then select to edit and then it is able to send it to gimp.

When I run xfce4-screenshot by command line and ask to send to gimp it seems that it is sending the wrong command to flatpak GIMP. How tell xfce4-screenshot which command to run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK the problem is that the flatpak redefines its own `/tmp`, and the other apps expect to exchange files via the real `/tmp`. Other unexpected segregations:

- Files you save/export from flatpak Gimp don't show in the "Recent" section of the file dialogs of other apps, because flatpak Gimp has its own `recently-used.xbel` file.
- The Python in Gimp isn't the one installed in the system. Modules you added to that one aren't available in Gimp (unless you reinstall them).